# Stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How to display only 1 record when insert in SQL? For this stored procedure, I created when insert it display 2 record with next day based on current date that selected.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

/**CREATED BY : GOTHISWARY  **/
/**DATE : 30-Nov-2020   **/

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_FINANCE]
    @StkDate datetime
AS    
    DECLARE
        @item1  varchar(50),
        @item2  varchar(50),
        @item3  varchar(50),
        @item4  varchar(50),
        @item5  varchar(50),
        @item6  varchar(50),
        @item7  varchar(50),
        @item8  varchar(50),
        @item9  varchar(50),
        @item10 varchar(50),
        @item11 varchar(50),
        @item12 varchar(50),
        @item13 varchar(50)
        
    SELECT
        @item1  = 'Nitrogen Gas',
        @item2  = 'Hyderogen Gas',
        @item3  = 'Sales Quantity - Trading',
        @item4 = 'Sales Quantity - MFG',
        @item5 = 'Sales in Quantity',
        @item6 = 'Ex-Factory',
        @item7 = 'Dlvd',
        @item8 = 'FOB',
        @item9 = 'CIF',
        @item10 = 'CFR',
        @item11 = 'Number of contract workers',
        @item12 = 'Number of staff in MFG',
        @item13 = 'Total number of Employee'

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FI_DailyMgt WHERE StkDate = @StkDate) 
    BEGIN
        ---- if yesterday no data, insert opening as zero.
        -- In the sql, all columns for float, set default value to zero.
        INSERT INTO FI_DailyMgt (StkDate,
                                 ITEM1_T, ITEM2_T, ITEM3_T, ITEM4_T, ITEM5_T,
                                 ITEM6_T, ITEM7_T, ITEM8_T, ITEM9_T, ITEM10_T,
                                 ITEM11_T, ITEM12_T, ITEM13_T,
                                 Crd_User, Crd_Date, Upd_User, Upd_Date)
        VALUES (@StkDate, 
                @item1, @item2, @item3, @item4, @item5,
                @item6, @item7, @item8, @item9, @item10, 
                @item11, @item12, @item13,
                0, GETDATE(), 0, NULL)
    END
    -- if yesterday got data, insert opening as yesterday's closing.
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE
                @UpdValue1      float,
                @UpdValue2      float,
                @UpdValue3      float,
                @UpdValue4      float,
                @UpdValue5      float,
                @UpdValue6      float,
                @UpdValue7      float,
                @UpdValue8      float,
                @UpdValue9      float,
                @UpdValue10     float,
                @UpdValue11     float,
                @UpdValue12     float,
                @UpdValue13     float
                
        SELECT
            @UpdValue1      = N2,
            @UpdValue2      = H2,
            @UpdValue3      = QtyTrading,
            @UpdValue4      = QtyMFG,
            @UpdValue5      = Qty,
            @UpdValue6      = ExFactory,
            @UpdValue7      = Dlvd,
            @UpdValue8      = FOB,
            @UpdValue9      = CIF,
            @UpdValue10     = CFR,
            @UpdValue11     = NoContractWorker,
            @UpdValue12     = NoStaffMFG,
            @UpdValue13     = TotNoEmployee
        FROM
            FI_DailyMgt 
        WHERE 
            StkDate = @StkDate

        UPDATE FI_DailyMgt 
        SET N2 = ISNULL(@UpdValue1, 0),
            H2 = ISNULL(@UpdValue2, 0),
            QtyTrading = ISNULL(@UpdValue3, 0),
            QtyMFG = ISNULL(@UpdValue4, 0),
            Qty = ISNULL(@UpdValue5, 0),
            ExFactory = ISNULL(@UpdValue6, 0),
            Dlvd = ISNULL(@UpdValue7, 0),
            FOB = ISNULL(@UpdValue8, 0),
            CIF = ISNULL(@UpdValue9, 0),
            CFR = ISNULL(@UpdValue10, 0),
            NoContractWorker = ISNULL(@UpdValue11, 0),
            NoStaffMFG = ISNULL(@UpdValue12, 0),
            TotNoEmployee = ISNULL(@UpdValue13, 0),
            ITEM1_T     = @item1,
            ITEM2_T     = @item2,
            ITEM3_T     = @item3,
            ITEM4_T     = @item4,
            ITEM5_T     = @item5,
            ITEM6_T     = @item6,
            ITEM7_T     = @item7,
            ITEM8_T     = @item8,
            ITEM9_T     = @item9,
            ITEM10_T    = @item10,
            ITEM11_T    = @item11,
            ITEM12_T    = @item12,
            ITEM13_T    = @item13
        WHERE
            StkDate= @StkDate 
    END
```

[image]

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: And **if** this is for **SQL Server**:  you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Please do not tell us that this is Urgent.  Maybe for you, but the volunteers here have other lives too.

Comment: Sounds to me as though you are passing the wrong date as StkDate - you are probably passing today instead of yesterday.  Not having all the code though, it is impossible to tell - just guessing

Comment: when i try to pass this exec dbo.sp_FINANCE '2021-05-26', it works but when i inside in the system it display following date together @JonathanWillcock.

Comment: Private Sub Insert_Update_Finance()
     
            xc.SetConnOpen_wtsdb()
            Dim sql As String = "sp_FINANCE"
            Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand(sql, xc.cn_wtsdb)
            With sqlcmd
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .Parameters.Add("@StkDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
                .Parameters("@StkDate").Value = CDate(dateLog.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With

            xc.SetConnClose_wtsdb()
        
    End Sub

Comment: Edit your question with more details, don't add these as comments.  Secondly pass your date parameter as a date, not as a string.

Comment: What is the value of dateLog?

Comment: this is the datelog 2021-05-26